# Make explicit stack algorithms faster

Tags: c++, recursion

There are some recursive algorithms that fill up the stack pretty quickly. One solution would be to make the stack explicit and thus turn the algorithm into an iterative one.

But I noticed that having explicit stacks makes algorithms quite a bit slower (which probably shouldn't have surprised me). Are there any general C++ guidelines for making explicit stacks faster? Is it possible for them to run faster even than the original recursive algorithms?

---

**Edit:** The function I wrote an explicit stack for is below. I also pasted the iterative code. For some reason, using `std::vector` rather than `std::stack` is faster, which is quite surprising.

```
// A(m, n) = n + 1                 if m = 0
//         = A(m - 1, 1)           if m > 0 and n = 0
//         = A(m - 1, A(m, n - 1)) if m, n > 0


int A(int m, int n, long& iterations,
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int> >& stack)
{
    stack.push_back(std::make_pair(m, n));
    long result = 0;
    bool result_available = false;

    while (stack.size() > 0)
    {
        iterations += 1;

        if (result_available) {
            stack.back().second = result;
            result_available = false;
        }

        m = stack.back().first;
        n = stack.back().second;
        stack.pop_back();

        if (m == 0) {
            result = n + 1;
            result_available = true;
        }
        else if (m > 0 && n == 0) {
            stack.push_back(std::make_pair(m - 1, 1));
        }
        else if (m > 0 && n > 0) {
            stack.push_back(std::make_pair(m - 1, n));
            stack.push_back(std::make_pair(m, n - 1));
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: This would be a lot easier to answer if you included an example of a recursive and explicit stack version of an algorithm where the timings differed significantly. It is hard to answer performance questions in general (beyond algorithmic complexity), because there are so many factors that influence performance.

Comment: Strictly guessing (as @Mankarse says, show some code), but creating stack frames is usually much faster than allocating heap memory, so if the iterative approach ends up expanding its stack frequently, you'll get a performance hit from the heap allocations. The solution is to make the allocations less frequent...

Comment: some types of recursion can be eliminated to a loop (tail recursion). Then you don't need the stack at all. It would be good to know the actual algorithm and the recursion behavior.

Comment: @Mankarse I added the original function and the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. try to allocate memory as seldom as possible from the heap. It's very slow.
2. eliminate tail recursion - for them you don't need a recursive call. It doesn't look as elegant as the recursive solution, but its faster. For an example how this is done, search for Fibonacci implementations. There are 2 recursive variants and a non recursive variant.
3. you won't be faster with the explicit stack as function calls & passing parameters via the stack are some of the fastest assembler instructions because they are used so often.

Comment: In the case of Fibonacci, let's not forget that the first improvement is to move to a O(N) implementation (thanks to memoization/dynamic programming)

Comment: yes - that's the second recursive algorithm with the tail recursion. But if you eliminate the tail recursion in that algorithm, it's even faster.

Answer (score 1):

There is another solution, for the lucky users of a recent version of gcc: `-fsplit-stack`.

Split stack is not a new idea, Lisp had it back then... it simply means that the compiler creates a program which does not have to setup its full stack up-front and will instead be able to extend it as necessary. The stack therefore become discontiguous.

Of course, this requires all (or most) libraries to be adapted for this new stack mechanism (thus requires recompiling the whole software stack). Libraries that are oblivious to it might still create a stack overflow exception, which is not so much an issue if you avoid using deeply recursive functions in such libraries.

With this mechanism, the stack will grow to accomodate your program as long as you have available memory.